# How to detect an incoming USB device in windows Service on Windows XP machine?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, windows-services, windows-xp

I an trying to write a simple Windows Service that shall detect any incoming USB device and Launch a GUI application.

```
            WqlEventQuery query = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 2");
            watcher.EventArrived += watcher_EventArrived;
            watcher.Query = query;
            watcher.Start();
            watcher.WaitForNextEvent();
```

This solution works well in Win 7 However, it fails in XP (I have XP SP3).

I found another solution here

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/63878/Enumerate-and-Auto-Detect-USB-Drives

This works very well in windows forms application even on windows XP, However it fails when I put it in service even on Win 7

Can you please help?

**EDIT 1:**
Presently there is no solution that works on win XP when we put the code in windows service.

Kind Regards

Bharat

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use both solutions, and then use the appropriate one depending on which version of Windows you are on.

Use the `System.Environment.OSVersion` property to tell you which version of windows you are on and then execute the CodeProject solution if it's earlier than Windows 7, and the other solution if it's Windows 7 or later.

You can read more about the information given back to you by the `System.Environment.OSVersion` property [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304283).

Comment: Thank you Martin for the quick answer. However, for win XP at present nothing works. Can you please throw some light on what should I use for XP